# Clojure `+` behaviour with nil values

Tags: clojure, nullpointerexception, clojurescript

Could someone explain the following behaviour of the [`+`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/+) function in Clojure (version "1.8.0")?

```
(+ 1)       ;; 1
(+ nil)     ;; nil
(+ 5 nil)   ;; java.lang.NullPointerException
(+ nil nil) ;; java.lang.NullPointerException
;; same behaviour with +'
```

Note : it doesn't throw an exception in ClojureScript :

```
(+ 1)       ;; 1
(+ nil)     ;; nil
(+ 5 nil)   ;; 5
(+ nil nil) ;; 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at the clojure's `+` source:

```
(defn +
  ([] 0)
  ([x] (cast Number x))
  ([x y] (. clojure.lang.Numbers (add x y)))
  ([x y & more]
     (reduce1 + (+ x y) more)))
```

so for the arity 1 it just casts a value to a Number. That really looks strange, that there is no check for `nil` here, i guess someone should submit this as a bug.

on the other hand the clojurescript's variant:

```
(defn ^number +
  ([] 0)
  ([x] x)
  ([x y] (cljs.core/+ x y))
  ([x y & more]
    (reduce + (cljs.core/+ x y) more)))
```

just returns the value (which also feels buggy, since `(+ "hello")` would return `"hello"` (well, haven't tested it, but still))

for other arities clojure uses `Numbers.add` (that requires numbers as params, and throws error),

while clojurescript uses this macro as far as I know:

```
(core/defmacro ^::ana/numeric +
  ([] 0)
  ([x] x)
  ([x y] (core/list 'js* "(~{} + ~{})" x y))
  ([x y & more] `(+ (+ ~x ~y) ~@more)))
```

so it's just the javascript addition, that adds nulls as zeros.

Comment: I think generally speaking Clojure adopts a ‘garbage in, garbage out’ attitude to argument validation, so I think it isn’t too surprising that `+` doesn’t care about the type of the arguments it’s given.

Comment: `(+ "hello") ;; java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.lang.Number`

Comment: well, yeah. clojure can't convert string to Number. `(+ "hello")` should work in clojurescript, not clojure

Comment: `cljs.user=> (+ "hello")
"hello"
cljs.user=> (+ nil "")
"null"
cljs.user=> (+ nil 123)
123 cljs.user=> (+ "123" nil)
"123null"`

Comment: @glts , yeah, but since it throws an error for arities 2+ , isn't it logical to throw it for arity 1 ? imagine this: `(apply + items)` where `items` is the result of some complex function call. So when items = [nil] it will return `nil`, but if items = [nil, 1, 2, nil] it will obviously throw an error. And when you use the result somewhere later, i bet you would rather see the exception, instead of reviewing all your code for this weird `nil` to find it in this really unexpected place (well personally i don't expect `nil` as an addition result)